# Error: "Unable to make http request" from custom assembly

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

My Data Lake Analytics job loads a custom .NET assembly that implements an `IExtractor`. This extractor works great when it merely rearranges data from a text file, for example, but what I really want to do is pull my input data from a vendor's remote API via HTTP. So I modify my extractor implementation to make what is essentially a REST request.

When I do *that* I get the error "Unable to make http request" in my Analytics log. I suppose it makes sense that Microsoft limits what you can and can't do within a custom assembly in Analytics, but I'm not finding anything in the documentation that says directly: *you can't make HTTP requests within a custom assembly.*

So my question is two parts:

1. Where are the limitations on custom assemblies in Azure Data Lake Analytics documented?
2. What is a better approach to pulling my input data into an Analytics job if I'm finding that massive static input files are an inelegant way of getting the most current data?

Comment: It would be good to know a good pattern for that as we have a similar requirement, eg Logic app, write to blob storage, would that work?

Comment: That's about what I'm doing now. Clearly I can't pull data "live" from my source service within U-SQL, so the next best thing is to have some external process grab it all in file form and shove it into Blob or Data Lake Store. It means I don't get a "real time" experience but for my application that's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limitation is going to be documented in the upcoming documentation on writing custom operators (planned to be published by end of year the latest).

I normally mention it in passing in my presentations, but I noticed it is not explicit in the slides. I will fix that :).

The main reason why we do not allow external calls is that a badly designed UDO that scales to a lot of data may look like a DDOS to that external service's REST endpoint, thus either shutting it down or putting Azure onto a black list.

Please let us know though what you would like to achieve over at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback and we will see if there are capabilities we can add to make this possible without the above mentioned drawback.